# Advanced Javascript filtering with objects

Tags: javascript, typescript

can somebody look at this code and tell me how can I filter my data by selectedOptions?

 Stackblitz code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-nwj1th?file=index.js

```
const data = [
  {
    name: 'Mateusz',
    age: 14,
  },
  {
    name: 'Tomek',
    age: 15,
  },
  {
    name: 'Jan',
    age: 12,
  },
];

const dataCopy = [...data];

const selectedOptions = [
  {
    age: [
      { value: 14, label: '14' },
      { value: 12, label: '12' },
    ],
    names: [{ value: 'Mateusz', label: 'Mateusz' }],
  },
];

const newData = data.filter((el) => {
  let isFiltered = false;
  selectedOptions.forEach((i) => {
    if (el.age === 14) {
      isFiltered = true;
    }
  });
  return isFiltered;
});

console.log(newData);
```

Comment: What do you mean by filtering my data by selectedOptions? What are the conditions? Should be age, name, both or something else?

Comment: In my example it should return this object {
    name: 'Mateusz',
    age: 14,
  },

Age and name should match the selectedOptions

Comment: I was trying to write some filter method but as you can see I cannot do that

Answer (score 1):

Instead of iterating through selectedOptions you can use the **some()** method to find if the specific age and the name exist in the selected options. If so, the condition will be fulfilled and the method will return the first matching record.

If you want to return a single object or an array, depending on how many records you have found you can use the [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to establish new value.

```js
const data = [{
    name: 'Mateusz',
    age: 14,
  },
  {
    name: 'Tomek',
    age: 15,
  },
  {
    name: 'Jan',
    age: 12,
  },
];

const selectedOptions = {
  age: [{
      value: 14,
      label: '14'
    },
    {
      value: 12,
      label: '12'
    },
  ],
  names: [{
    value: 'Mateusz',
    label: 'Mateusz'
  }],
};

const newData = data.filter((el) => {
  return selectedOptions.age.some((element) => element.value === el.age) &&
    selectedOptions.names.some((element) => element.value === el.name)
});

const objOrArray = newData.length > 1 ? newData : newData[0];

console.log(objOrArray);
```

Comment: What if I'll have some more options and more data to process and got to return array of objects?

Comment: So, you want to return sometimes a single object and sometimes an array based on the content selectedOptions, right?

Comment: Also, will the selectedOptions always have one object in which there will be two parameters __age__ and __name__ with multiple _options_ or the selectedOptions can contain more records? I am wondering because I do not understand why it is an array instead of an object.

Comment: Correct, and I thought that using object in array for selectedOptions will be easier to transform

Comment: I assume that "correct" was regarding my first comment and regarding the second, there will not be any obstacles to change selectedOptions into the object?

Comment: Yea, it can also be object